# Homework Problem Expected Value MM estimator, Correct?

Tags: probability, integration, expected-value

We are given the following density function:

$$
f_{\theta}(x) = \frac{\theta}{x^2} I\{x\in [\theta, \infty] \}, \theta > 0
$$

and are supposed to calculated the methods of moments estimator. To do so, I frist calculate the expected value:

\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f_{\theta}(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \frac{\theta}{x^2} I\{x\in [\theta, \infty] \} dx &= \int_{0}^{\theta} x \frac{\theta}{x^2} I\{x\in [\theta, \infty] \} dx + \int_{\theta}^{\infty} x \frac{\theta}{x^2} I\{x\in [\theta, \infty] \} dx \\
&= 0 + \int_{\theta}^{\infty} x \frac{\theta}{x^2} dx = \theta (ln(\infty) - ln(\theta)) = \infty
\end{align}

Thus the expected value does not exist. Hence the MM estimator does not exist. Is my argument correct?

Comment: it absolutly does. would not have come up with that idea. what a great solution.